# How to prove that a mapping is homomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ f:(A, \cdot) \to (B, \ast) $ and $g:(B,\ast) \to (C,\times)$ be Operation preserving maps.
Then I must prove that $ g \circ f$ is an operation preserving map too.
 This is what I have so far:
Since $f$ is a homomorphism $(A, \cdot)$ and $(B, \ast)$ are groups and $ f(x \cdot y)=f(x)\ast f(y)$
Since $(C,\times)$ is a group so $g(f(x)\ast (f(y))=g(f(x)) \times g(f(y))$.
Hence $ g\circ f$ is homomorphic.

Comment: What is 'operation preserving maps'? Do you want to prove that composition of homomorphisms is homomorphism?

Comment: An operation preserving map I think is another way of saying that a function is homomorphic. My textbook uses the weirdest terms

Comment: You should probably write out the *full* line: $$(g\circ f)(x\cdot y)=g(f(x\cdot y))=g(f(x)*f(y))=g(f(x))\times g(f(y))=(g\circ f)(x)\times(g\circ f)(y).$$ That's all you have to do, right?

Comment: $(g\circ f)(x\cdot y)=g(f(x\cdot y))=g(f(x)\ast f(y))=g(f(x))xg(f(y))=(g\circ f)(x)x(g\circ f)(y)$

Comment: It would be better to use `\times` ($\times$) instead of overuse the letter $x$...

Comment: @anon, you have typed faster than me... lol

Comment: @anon Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composition, in order to be "operation preserving", must fulfill $$(g \circ f)(x \cdot y) = g(f(x\cdot y)) = (g \circ f)(x) \times (g \circ f)(y).$$

Since $f$ preserves the operation $\cdot$, we have $g(f(x\cdot y) = g(f(x) \ast f(y))$, where $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are elements of $B$ and since $g$ preserves the operation $\ast$, we get $g(f(x) \ast f(y)) = g(f(x)) \times g(f(y))$ and we're done.